# Один цикл для нескольких списков

Tags: python, список

Есть 24 списка. Каждый из них хранит по 10 элементов вида (1671, 945).
Есть ли возможность в одном цикле пройти все 240 элементов из 10 списков?

P.S мне нужно имеено 10 списков, сделать один список с 240 элементами нельзя.

```
for cord in (что то тут)
  pyautogui.click(cord)
```

Comment: посмотрите функцию zip()

Comment: у вас какой-то странный проект - вы его сами не делаете - вы задали два десятка вопросов, и за вас его пишет stackoverflow. почему?

Comment: Я задал здесь 2 десятка вопросов, из 20 000 вопросов, которые у меня возникали, задавал только те вопросы, которые самостоятельно быстро решать не получалось, я только-только начал изучать питон, поэтому знаю только базовые вещи, и то не все.

Comment: Беда в том, что задав тут хоть 2 хоть 20 десятков таких вопросов Python вы не выучите. Уже писал -  повторю: на подсказках соседа по парте можно учительку свою обмануть. Но научиться ничему нельзя. Вы бы не проектом занялись, а хоть бы одну книжечку тоненькую по Python самостоятельно осилили бы. Глядишь, все ваши 20 вопросов - ответы на которые вы в сумме прождали часов 40, вы бы самостоятельно решили минут за 40.

Comment: Да понятное дело, просто для меня проект как мотивация изучать язык, но мои знания пока настолько малы, что получая ответы на вопросы я расширяю базу знаний

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Надо делать не один список из 240 элементов, а список из 24 списков по 10 элементов каджый.
И тогда все элементарно
(3 на три только для примера, на самом деле код работает при любом количестве и при любом размере каждого списка)

```
list1=[1,2,3]
list2=[4,5,6]
list3=[7,8,9]
list=[list1,list2,list3]
for lt in list:
    for ltn in lt:
        print(ltn)
```

Результат:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

А вообще, это изучают на первом уроке по циклам. Вы хоть в учебник заглядывали? Или все на подсказках соседа по парте?